# Is it possible to activate a cell for text entry only if a condition is met in another cell?

Tags: excel

I'm capturing survey results into a spreadsheet and have several listboxes some with has 'OTher' as an option in the list. if Other is selected I want to make the next cell in the row active for text entry, otherwise it's inactive. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you saying users shouldn't be able to enter anything in that cell unless "Other" is selected ?  It might be better to use conditional formatting to highlight the next cell when "Other" is selected: trying 100% to restrict data entry is difficult, but prompting for entry when required is more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Go to the Data ribbon and select `Data Validation` from the Data Tools.

At settings you choose custom and use the following formula:

```
=IF(A2="Others", ISTEXT(A1),1)
```

Please note, that you have to change A1 and A2 according to your needs.

You can even specify an Input Message and an Error Message, if some one doesn't enter the correct format.